# How do I trigger virus check on files in Google Drive API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to check the Google Drive virus checking behavior through the API. Through the Google Drive UI, I can download the file and it tells me it is infected with a virus. However, when I download the same file that was uploaded through the API, it doesn't give me any notification and lets me download the infected file.

How can I get the API to tell me if I'm trying to download a virus infected file?

Comment: Are you certain that it is Google telling you that the file is a virus or might it be your locally installed AntiVirus software?

Comment: I cannot download files google thinks have a virus with the api, using the gdrive client program. I get an error with `"reason": "cannotDownloadAbusiveFile"`.

Answer (score 1):

The results of the file scan are not currently exposed in the API.